# Add variable in api request angular

Tags: angular, api

I have a function that take a id as parameter and do :

```
onChooseVehicle(id){

      console.log(id);

      this.router.navigate(['tracking/v/-- id must be here --/live'])

  }
```

output of id : 4

that means i have successfully receive data, how i put this id in url here ?

```
      this.router.navigate(['tracking/v/ --HERE -- /live'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
this.router.navigate([`tracking/v/${id}/live`]);  // notice the back ticks `` instead of quotes ''
```

or string concatenation

```js
this.router.navigate(['tracking/v/' + id + '/live']);  // here using quotes ''
```

You can't mix them.

Comment: You help me with two questions, my original question and what difference between `` and '' .
Thanks you !  @Michael D